# Changes in JAXB not reflecting in soap response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have a very simple web service implementation as shown below

```
package implementation;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class WhatsMyName {

@WebMethod
public String getMyName(){
    return "John Smith";
}
```

}

I ran a wsgen on my implementation class file to generate JAXB classes and WSDLs ( along with XSD )

The SOAP response when i try calling this method is as  below

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getMyNameResponse xmlns:ns2="http://implementation/">
         <return>John Smith</return>
      </ns2:getMyNameResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What should i do if i want to generate a response like below

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:NameResponse xmlns:ns2="http://implementation/">
         <Name>John Smith</Name>
      </ns2:NameResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I did try changing the generated ( by wsgen) JAXB response class to have @XmlType(name = "NameResponse", namespace = "http://implementation/")  and @XmlRootElement(name = "NameResponse", namespace = "http://implementation/") but the soap response xml still remains the same.

Whenever i try to change @XmlElement(name = "return", namespace = "") in the same response class to @XmlElement(name = "Name", namespace = ""), i get the below runtime error while executing the publisher that publishes this web service impl.

```
WebServiceException: class implementation.jaxws.GetMyNameResponse do not have a property of the name return
```

I just started learning SOAP and i did google this exception but with no fruitful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the annotation `@WebResult`.

In this case the code could be

```
@WebService
public class WhatsMyName {

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "Name")
public String getMyName(){
    return "John Smith";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see that after adding the WebResult, the wsgen generated response message added '@XmlElement(name = "Name", namespace = "")' above the return field. It is weird that it did not work before when i explicitly changed the JAXB class.  So changes in JAXB generated classes will not work in SOAP ?

Comment: It seems so but I also think it's weird. Unfortunately I'm not that used to JAXB and SOAP to give you a correct anwer.

Comment: I think i am gonna mark your answer as the correct one since it got me the solution to my core problem.